# Regex.Match help: -93-11.html, want to get 11 (example)

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-7

I need your help regarding RegexMatch (c#) for file endings:

I need always the number between the extension .html and before the first minus (if you read from right to left)

example:

-213.html
looking for 213

-93-32.html
looking for 32

I tried already -([^\"]*).html, but in the secone example it gives me -93-32 back.

(btw. with my current solution above, i also get the minus, if you know how i can exlude it, please let me know, currently i'm doing a replace "-" with "" afterwards)

Thanks in advance,
 Ralf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(\d+)\.html$` should do it. here `$` means end of the line anchor.

If you dont want to capture `.html` use `(\d+)(?:\.html)$` ( haven't tested it though ).

Without anchor, if you read left to right, it would be `-(\d+)\.html`

Comment: Crazy stuff i will never understand it. I tried your first solution and it works great. Is there also a way to get rid of .html at the end? because i get now e.g. 32.html i use now Regex.Match(getpagefirst1, "(\\d+)\\.html$");

Comment: Regex are hard to understand. But once understood, you'll be tempted to use it everywhere.

Comment: @RalfRymer on your update to the comment I have updated my answer.

Comment: still there, but i do a replace afterwards and it works perfectly, thx again & have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is `"-([0-9]+?).html"`

Comment: You should escape the `.` and there is no need to make the repetition ungreedy

Comment: @climbage it doesn't, you should get the result on match. match.Result("$1");

Comment: @m.buettner there is no need to escape point, as in this case it's exactly one char before html so doesn't matter which one

Comment: @VladL if the file name isn't the entire string, you might get other matches though which are not file names. plus, it's something the OP should be aware of

Comment: @m.buettner well, since we don't know if the file name is entire string or not, my regex will match all occurences